# $\int_{n}^{\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-t} dt \to ? \ \ \ (\text{Re}(z)>0)$

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Let $z\in \mathbb C$ with $\text{Re}(z)>0$ (that is, $z=x+iy, x>0$), it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Main_definition) that 
$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt.$$

Let $n\in\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\},$ and define $I_n(z)=\int_{n}^{\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-t} dt \  \ \ (\text{Re}(z)>0).$

> Question: What can we say about $I_n(z)$? Can expect to evolute $I_n$? What can we say about $I_n$ as $n\to \pm \infty$?

Comment: $I_n(z) = \Gamma(z, n)$, where $\Gamma(z, s)$ is the (upper) incomplete Gamma function. For fixed $z$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Gamma(z, n) = 0$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: @Travis: Thanks. What  about $n\to -\infty$? Can you suggest  something?

Comment: @abcd As my answer mentions, the limit to negative infinity does not exist.  It diverges to $+\infty$ exponentially fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Travis mentions, this is the [(upper) incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function):

$$\Gamma(z,s)=\int_s^{+\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\ dt$$

It is known that $\lim_{s\to+\infty}\Gamma(z,s)=0$ and $\lim_{s\to-\infty}\Gamma(z,s)$ does not exist for any $z$.  The limit to infinity may easily be verified with a squeeze on upper bounds.

By integration by parts, it can be seen that

$$\Gamma(z+1,s)=z\Gamma(z,s)+s^ze^{-s}$$

If $z\in\mathbb N$, closed form may be found by letting $t-s=u$,

$$\Gamma(z,s)=e^{-s}\int_0^{+\infty}(u+s)^{z-1}e^{-u}\ du$$

and then binomial expanding into the Gamma function.  Values at half integers will reduce to the error function, and negative integers reduce to the exponential integral.

A nice asymptotic expansion also reveals that

$${\displaystyle {\frac {\Gamma (s,x)}{x^{s-1}e^{-x}}}\rightarrow 1}\text{ as }{\displaystyle x\rightarrow +\infty }$$

$${\displaystyle {\frac {\Gamma (s,x)}{x^{s}}}\rightarrow -{\frac {1}{s}}}\text{ as }{\displaystyle x\rightarrow 0}$$

$${\displaystyle \Gamma (s,z)\sim z^{s-1}e^{-z}\sum _{k=0}{\frac {\Gamma (s)}{\Gamma (s-k)}}z^{-k}}$$